# How to change legend name in WPF Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

[image: chart]

Hi!

This is WPF Toolkit line chart.

Does anyone know how to change Series1 text programmaticaly?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try _anything_?

Comment: I tried google, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LineSeries Title=" Monthly Count" is responsible for display the legend text

```
<wpft:Chart Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10" Name="mcChart"
       Width="400" Height="250"
       Background="LightSteelBlue">
    <wpft:Chart.Series>
     <wpft:LineSeries Title=" Monthly Count"
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
</wpft:LineSeries>
</wpft:Chart.Series>           
</wpft:Chart>
```

Answer (score 1):

the series has a Title value

```
                               Title="Deliveries by Hour"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Margin="10">
        <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries Title="Total added"
                                    DependentValuePath="Value"
                                    IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                    IsSelectionEnabled="True"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding [0]}" />
        <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries Title="Sent"
                                    DependentValuePath="Value"
                                    IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                    IsSelectionEnabled="True"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding [1]}" />
        <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries Title="3+ hours overdue"
                                    DependentValuePath="Value"
                                    IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                    IsSelectionEnabled="True"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding [2]}" />
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```